# VBA Access Conditional Formatting Reset New Record

Tags: ms-access, vba, conditional-formatting

I have created a database with one form and one table.  The form is basically an application and asks questions about each person/applicant.  I've written skip logic/conditional formatting in different events for disabling/enabling certain questions or text; as well as used Access's built-in Conditional Formatting for enabling and disabling text fields and other controls.

For times when I want to disabled Checkboxes, Access's conditional formatting is not an option for this type of control, so I have written VBA code to disable these checkboxes based on the lead-in questions, which works great.  The issue that I am having is that if I finish an applicant and some fields have become disabled as a result of my VBA, when I create a new record, those fields remain disabled, whereas, the fields that I used the Conditional Formatting tool are reset correctly.

Its my understanding that I will need to write some code to reset these controls for when there is a new record.  I wasn't sure which Form event to use.  Also, I want to preserve what has been enabled and disabled as I review records.   So if I go back to a record where a checkbox was disabled, it remains disabled, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `Form_Current` event.  This event fires once each time you go to a record.

As a result, it fires in the following situations:

- When you open the form
- When you move to an existing record
- When you move to an empty record